# Serialization Exception In a class inheriting from ModelBase in Catel Framework

Tags: c#, serialization, catel

After the upgrade Catel (3.9->4.2). In debugged code in an exception with a deep copy using serialization/deserialization and I found that if the class implements IEnumerable, I catch the exception.
"System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException" in mscorlib.dll
VS2012  .NET4.5

class

```
[Serializable]
public class Test : ModelBase, IEnumerable<int>
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> List { get; set; }



    public Test()
    {
        List= new List<int>{25,63,59,88};
        Name = "tretret";
        Count = 89;
    }

     public Test(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("SerializationInfo");
     }


     public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
     {
         return List.GetEnumerator();
     }

     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
     {
         return GetEnumerator();
     }
}
```

I know that you want to use IncludeInSerialization attribute for inclusion prop in serialization.

DeepClone function

```
      public static T DeepClone<T>(T source) where T : class
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream); // Exception here!!
    }
```

Caller

```
var classTest = new Test();
var classTestClone = SimpleDeepClone.DeepClone(classTest);
```

Comment: Create an issue in the official issue tracker please: http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker

Comment: An `IEnumerable` isn't inherently a very serializable thing. It represents some (possibly unbounded) sequence of values. You should use `ICollection` instead. Not entirely sure if this is causing your problem, but can't hurt to try.

Comment: I do not need the whole implementation of ICollection. only need enumerator

Comment: @Aldmi If you implement `IReadOnlyCollection` you only need to implement `Count` and `GetEnumerator`, which you already have. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I realized IReadOnlyCollection but an exception is not disappear ((

Comment: Do you recommend to write in Catel tracker?